# С++ перегруженные операции с абстрактным базовым классом

Tags: c++, ооп

### Описание кода

Итак, есть набор классов для работы с фигурами.

```
class Figure;
class Circle;
class Rectangle;
class UnitedFigure;
class ComplementedFigure;
class IntersectedFigure;
```

Класс `Figure` - базовый и абстрактный. И выглядит так:

```
class Figure {
public:
    virtual double distance_to (const Point &p) const = 0;

    friend UnitedFigure operator + (Figure & f1, Figure & f2);
    friend ComplementedFigure operator - (Figure & f1, Figure & f2);
    friend IntersectedFigure operator & (Figure & f1, Figure & f2);
    bool is_point_into(const Point &p) const {
        return distance_to(p) <= 0;
    }
};
```

Все остальные фигуры публично наследуют `Figure`, имеют разные конструкторы и перегруженный метод `distance_to()`.

```
class Circle : public Figure {...};

class Rectangle : public Figure {...};

class UnitedFigure : public Figure {...};

class ComplementedFigure : public Figure {...};

class IntersectedFigure : public Figure {...};

UnitedFigure operator + (Figure & f1, Figure & f2) {
    return UnitedFigure{f1, f2};
}

ComplementedFigure operator - (Figure & f1, Figure & f2) {
    return ComplementedFigure{f1, f2};
}

IntersectedFigure operator & (Figure & f1, Figure & f2) {
    return IntersectedFigure{f1, f2};
}
```

### Предмет вопроса

Эти описания позволяют мне задавать фигуры вот таким образом:

```
// Создаём нужные примитивы
Circle big(Point{0, 0}, 20);
Circle small(Point{0, 0}, 10);
Rectangle quarter_1(Point{0, 0}, Point{10, 10});
Rectangle quarter_3(Point{0, 0}, Point{-10, -10});

// Собираем фигуру
auto quarter_1_and_3 = quarter_1 + quarter_3;
auto inner_empty_space = small - quarter_1_and_3;
auto figure = big - inner_empty_space;
```

Однако если я попытаюсь описать фигуру без лишних переменных одним выражением, то получу ошибку, так как операции ожидают в качестве операндов ссылки на базовый класс, а не объекты-значения конкретных классов.

```
// Собираем фигуру
auto figure = big - (small - (quarter_1 + quarter_3)); // Ошибка операндов
```

Предмет конфликта: абстрактный класс + ссылки VS работа с операндами по значению.

**Как модифицировать классы так, чтобы можно было описывать одним выражением, как выше?**

**UPD1:**
МВП

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>

class Point;
class Figure;
class Circle;
class Rectangle;
class UnitedFigure;
class ComplementedFigure;
class IntersectedFigure;

class Point {
public:
    double x;
    double y;

    Point() = default;
    Point(double _x, double _y) : x(_x), y(_y) {}

    Point operator + (const Point& p) const {
        return Point {x + p.x, y + p.y};
    }
    Point operator - (const Point& p) const {
        return Point {x - p.x, y - p.y};
    }

    static Point max (const Point& p1, const Point& p2) {
        return Point {std::max(p1.x, p2.x), std::max(p1.y, p2.y)};
    }

    double vec_length () const {
        return sqrt(x*x + y*y);
    }
};

class Figure {
public:
    virtual double distance_to (const Point &p) const = 0;
    friend UnitedFigure operator + (Figure & f1, Figure & f2);
    friend ComplementedFigure operator - (Figure & f1, Figure & f2);
    friend IntersectedFigure operator & (Figure & f1, Figure & f2);
    bool is_point_into(const Point &p) const {
        return distance_to(p) <= 0;
    }
};

class Circle : public Figure {
    Point o;
    double r;

public:
    Circle (Point p, double _r) : o(p), r(_r) {}

    double distance_to (const Point &p) const override {
        return (o - p).vec_length() - r;
    }
};

class Rectangle : public Figure {
    Point a;
    Point b;

public:
    Rectangle (Point p1, Point p2) : a(p1), b(p2) {}

    double distance_to (const Point &p) const override {
        auto d = Point::max(a - p, p - b);
        return Point::max(d, Point {0, 0}).vec_length() + std::min(0.0, std::max(d.x, d.y));
    }
};

class UnitedFigure : public Figure {
    Figure &f1;
    Figure &f2;

public:
    UnitedFigure (Figure &_f1, Figure &_f2) : f1(_f1), f2(_f2) {}

    double distance_to(const Point &p) const override {
        return std::min(f1.distance_to(p), f2.distance_to(p));
    }
};

class ComplementedFigure : public Figure {
    Figure &f1;
    Figure &f2;

public:
    ComplementedFigure (Figure &_f1, Figure &_f2) : f1(_f1), f2(_f2) {}

    double distance_to(const Point &p) const override {
        return std::max(f1.distance_to(p), -f2.distance_to(p));
    }
};

class IntersectedFigure : public Figure {
    Figure &f1;
    Figure &f2;

public:
    IntersectedFigure (Figure &_f1, Figure &_f2) : f1(_f1), f2(_f2) {}

    double distance_to(const Point &p) const override {
        return std::max(f1.distance_to(p), f2.distance_to(p));
    }
};

UnitedFigure operator + (Figure & f1, Figure & f2) {
    return UnitedFigure{f1, f2};
}

ComplementedFigure operator - (Figure & f1, Figure & f2) {
    return ComplementedFigure{f1, f2};
}

IntersectedFigure operator & (Figure & f1, Figure & f2) {
    return IntersectedFigure{f1, f2};
}

int main() {
    Circle big(Point{0, 0}, 20);
    Circle small(Point{0, 0}, 10);
    Rectangle quarter_1(Point{0, 0}, Point{10, 10});
    Rectangle quarter_3(Point{0, 0}, Point{-10, -10});

    auto quarter_1_and_3 = quarter_1 + quarter_3;
    auto inner_empty_space = small - quarter_1_and_3;
    auto figure = big - inner_empty_space;
    
//    auto figure = big - (small - (quarter_1 + quarter_3));

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Видимо тут проблема в некорректной сигнатуре перегруженных операторов, требующих модифицируемых объектов, но не модифицирующих их, что, среди прочего, делает невозможным использование выражений prvalue в качестве операндов. Точнее сказать нельзя, так как в не удосужились привести [mcve].

Comment: @user7860670 `Figure` - класс абстрактный, его нельзя передать по значению

Comment: где в моем предыдущем комментарии написано, что их можно или нужно передавать по значению?

Comment: @user7860670 `требующих модифицируемых объектов`

Comment: Ну как так... Что в фразе "требующих модифицируемых объектов" можно интерпретировать как "передачу про значению"? Там же нет ни слова "передача", ни "по значению". И описывает она код из примера, где идет передача по ссылке.

Comment: Поставьте `const` везде, где параметры/члены класса не меняются

Comment: @user7860670 мы так перейдем от обсуждения темы вопроса к обсуждению формулировок, к чистейшей демагогии. Не есть гуд.

Comment: @dIm0n тогда мы получим ошибку при попытке создать объекты классов `UnitedFigure` и прочих

Comment: @MaxLevs если всё будет константным, то не должно быть ошибок. Лично я не вижу, где вы как-то меняете `Figure`, но при этом передаёте и храните его как потенциально модифицирующийся, о чём вам уже сказали в 1 комментарии

Comment: Всё, преодолел. Благодарю dIm0n и user7860670 за помощь.

Answer (score 1):

До этого вопроса я думал, что поле класса как ссылочный тип заводить нельзя.

Компилятор ругается на то, что вы передаете rvalue в функцию как non-const ссылку.

Время жизни объекта полученного при помощи (quarter_1 + quarter_3) не выходит за пределы выражения во всей строке.
Вы передаете полученный объект в `operator -`, который в свою очередь передает его в конструктор `ComplementedFigure`, который присвоит ссылку в `f2` на этот временный объект, так делать не нужно.
В итоге у вас будет недействительная ссылка в поле `ComplementedFigure::f2` после перехода к следующему выражению после строки `auto figure = big - (small - (quarter_1 + quarter_3));`.

Пользуйтесь ссылочными полями класса с осторожностью, а лучше вообще не пользуйтесь.

Рекомендую почитать в чем опасность использования ссылки\указателя на объект из другой области видимости и как это обойти (при помощи умных указателей и RAII)